# Heartbeating to <hostname>:7182 failed during Cloudera Installation on 3 node cluster

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am creating a 3 node cloudera cluster using Cloudera Manager.I followed the cloudera document :

[1]https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_ig_install_path_b.html#concept_wkg_kpb_pn

After login to cloudera manager and entering the hostnames of the 3 nodes, when I try to install it gives the below message:

Installation failed. Failed to receive heartbeat from agent.
Ensure that the host's hostname is configured properly.
Ensure that port 7182 is accessible on the Cloudera Manager Server (check firewall rules).
Ensure that ports 9000 and 9001 are not in use on the host being added.
Check agent logs in /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/ on the host being added. (Some of the logs can be found in the installation details).
If Use TLS Encryption for Agents is enabled in Cloudera Manager (Administration -> Settings -> Security), ensure that /etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini has use_tls=1 on the host being added. Restart the corresponding agent and click the Retry link here.

I checked the agent logs and it has error messassge :Heartbeating to hostname:7182 failed during Cloudera Installation on 3 node cluster.

where hostname is the external IP of my node 
I checked that the inbound port 7182 is open and also verified that tls is set to 1.

I checked the /etc/hosts and it has the below entries:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Please advice whether the /etc/hosts file has to be changed and what should I replace the content with?

Comment: Please check the DNS. This means: on each hosts all hostnames should be able ro resolve to IP address and vice versa. This can be done by proper configuration of DNS or putting a pairs of "IP hostname" into /etc/hosts. This file should contain all IPs and hostnames of cluster machines.

Answer (score 1):

Resolution: When the installation got stopped and it restarted all over once again. I did two things :

1) Disabled firewall by doing iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT iptables -F .

2) The second thing is giving internal IP instead of external IP while adding hosts.

It worked fine this time and gave no errors.